# .getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, jsx

Hello I'm new in JS and probably is something more wrong in the code.
But I don't understand why `getAttribute` is not a function.

Test:

```js
test('TESTING', () => {
    const filterNodes = [
        <div key='1' value='foo' />,
        <div key='2' value='bar' />
    ]
    const filtersKeyValue = {
        key: ['0', '1', '1', '3'],
        value: ['foo', 'bar', 'toto', 'react']
    }

    expect(fillReportSpecFiltersWithValues(filterNodes, filtersKeyValue)).toBe()
})
```

Code:

```js
export const fillReportSpecFiltersWithValues = (filterNodes, filtersKeyValue = {}) => {
    for (const key in filtersKeyValue) {
        const value = filtersKeyValue[key]
        for (const filterNode of filterNodes) {
            if (filterNode.getAttribute('key') === key) {
                filterNode.setAttribute('value', value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is very much appreciated?

Comment: Your `filterNodes` is an array of what?

Comment: @Amadeus Looks like React nodes.

Comment: @keul I think those tags were relevant.  If anything [tag:jsx] is relevant since it looks like the OP is using JSX.

Comment: @zero298 yeah is react

Comment: It's not an HTMLCollection, and the children don't have a `getAttribute` method. You can simply use `filterNode.key` though. Whenever you get `x.y is not a function`, chances are `x` isn't what you expect it to be. The first order of debugging is to `console.log(x)`

Comment: @ChrisG can't change the code of Code, just the testing, I'm an intern and I'm really new into this...Can you tell me something to change in testing code?

Comment: You would have to replace `filterNode.getAttribute('key')` with `filterNode.key`. If you can only change the test code, you need to put actual `HTMLElement`s in `filterNodes`. You can use `document.createElement()` for that. [Like this](https://pastebin.com/g3gj5yep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your job is to test `fillReportSpecFiltersWithValues`.

It accepts an array of objects that have `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` properties, and an object representing key/value pairs.

Instead of testing it by creating mocked DOM elements, just test it by creating appropriate mock objects:

```
test('fillReportSpecFiltersWithValues', () => {
  const filterNodes = [
    { getAttribute: () => '1', setAttribute: jest.fn() },
    { getAttribute: () => '2', setAttribute: jest.fn() },
    { getAttribute: () => '3', setAttribute: jest.fn() }
  ]
  const filtersKeyValue = {
    '1': 'foo',
    '2': 'bar'
  }

  fillReportSpecFiltersWithValues(filterNodes, filtersKeyValue);

  expect(filterNodes[0].setAttribute).toHaveBeenCalledWith('value', 'foo');  // Success!
  expect(filterNodes[1].setAttribute).toHaveBeenCalledWith('value', 'bar');  // Success!
  expect(filterNodes[2].setAttribute).not.toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code

```js
const filterNodes = [
    <div key='1' value='foo' />,
    <div key='2' value='bar' />
]
```

creates a set of Objects that represent React nodes.  They aren't actually HTMLElements or DOM nodes yet until you call `ReactDOM.render()`.

Consider the following that prints the Object represented by a JSX expression.  It doesn't have the methods that you are trying to call.  You need to adjust your test to look at the properties the Object *does* have or possibly render the JSX Objects to the DOM and *then* treat them as HTMLElements.

```js
// JSX to construct an anchor with an href
const bar = "http://example.com";
const foo = <a href={bar}>anchor</a>; 

// Prints the JSX Object definition
console.log(foo);

// This will actually populate the DOM with the JSX definition
const dom = ReactDOM.render(foo, document.getElementById("fizz"));

// The rendered DOM node
console.log(dom);

// The attribute pulled from the DOM node
console.log(dom.getAttribute("href"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="fizz"></div>
```

Considering that, your code test code should probably look more like this where you `map()` your JSX Objects through `ReactDOM.render()` so that they become HTMLElements:

```js
test('TESTING', () => {
  // Make someplace to put the elements that you want converted
  const app = document.getElementById("foo");
  
  // Map them through ReactDOM.render() to make elements
  const filterNodes = [
    <div key='1' value='foo' />,
    <div key='2' value='bar' />
  ].map(n => ReactDOM.render(n, app));

  // Sanity check
  console.log(filterNodes);

  const filtersKeyValue = {
    key: ['0', '1', '1', '3'],
    value: ['foo', 'bar', 'toto', 'react']
  }

  expect(fillReportSpecFiltersWithValues(filterNodes, filtersKeyValue)).toBe()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Understand what are you saying. But really don't know how to correct mine :(

Comment: @Jonathan See my edit.  I don't know how Jest deals with interacting with the DOM, but if you can't change the code, and the code wants an Array of HTMLElements, you need to convert your JSX to HTMLElement with `ReactDOM.render()`.

Comment: This seems fine in principle, however the `key` attribute doesn't end up in the DOM. So `filterNode.getAttribute('key')` doesn't make sense in a React environment.

Comment: @ChrisG You're right.  I suppose the easiest way to get the test to pass is to just use the raw DOM API instead of trying to force it through JSX and React.

Comment: also I have this error `Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.` :(

Comment: @zero298 any suggestion in how to do it?

Comment: @Jonathan Try `.map(n => ReactDOM.render(n, document.body));` instead.  There is likely not a `<div>` in your DOM during testing.